# Set to right order icon in a html table

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I have this column:

```
<th rowspan="2">Name <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>
```

Here the result:

[image]

As you can see the order icon is down the column name, while I'd like to keep it always next to the name.
any idea?

**UPDATE**
thanks to dfsq comment, I changed the code above and I fix my problem:

```
<th rowspan="2" style="white-space: nowrap;">Name <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sort"></i></th>
```

Comment: to all the datas?

Comment: you should provide your whole source code better.

Comment: Well, you could fix it with `th {white-space: nowrap;}` but you need to make sure your table is can stretch so icon is not outside.

Comment: thanks dfsq, if you rewirte it as answer I set it as correct